# Convert CRC32 sum from LSB-first algorithm to sum for MSB-first algorithm

Tags: algorithm, go, crc, crc32

CRC32 sums can be represented either as least significant bit first or most significant bit first. For example the IEEE CRC32 polynomial can be represented as either `0xedb88320` or `0x4c11db7`, with associated changes to the CRC32 algorithm as shown here (Go code).

LSB-first algorithm (reverse representation):

```
func crc32Update(crc uint32, tab *table, p []byte) uint32 {
    crc = ^crc
    for _, v := range p {
        crc = tab[byte(crc)^v] ^ (crc >> 8)
    }
    return ^crc
}
```

MSB-first algorithm (normal representation):

```
func crc32Update(crc uint32, tab *table, p []byte) uint32 {
    crc = ^crc
    for _, v := range p {
        crc = tab[byte(crc>>24)^v] ^ (crc << 8)
    }
    return ^crc
}
```

(These have associated bit reversal changes in the CRC32 table construction that I don't include here, but see these two playground implementations for [LSB and MSB](https://play.golang.org/p/KJrgM6i7h7b) including a call to the Go std library implementation).

As described in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Reversed_representations_and_reciprocal_polynomials) it is possible to convert the LSB algorithm sum to an MSB sum. However, it is not clear to me how this would be implemented. As far as I understand, the article linked says that the there is a way to inter-convert between the two sums according to $G(x) = x^nG(x^-1)$, but I don't understand how I would go about using this relationship.

Can anyone point me to documentation explaining this better than the WP article does so that I can code this up?

The reason for this question is that the standard library in Go provides fast LSB-first implementations, but I am having to deal with inputs that have been summed using the MSB-first algorithm (MPEG-TS packet video streams).

Comment: To clarify Matt Timmermans answer, the wiki article includes a section on reciprocal polynomials. The wiki article mentions "codeword", which is a message and an appended CRC, then goes on to explain if all but the first n bits of a codeword are reversed, then the reciprocal polynomial used to generate a new CRC, that CRC will equal the reverse of the first n bits of the codeword. This is not how a LSB CRC can be converted into a MSB CRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually convert a CRC into the reciprocal version, but that is not what you need to do.  You certainly *can* use the standard library function you have to implement the CRC that you want.

Both update functions do the same thing, but they use a different byte order in the CRC polynomial itself.

To make your MSB table work for the LSB update function, just byte-reverse every entry.  When you're done, byte-reverse the result.

I've shown that in your implementation here:  https://play.golang.org/p/VxuZIrTiens

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The table reversal was clearly the thing that I did not try.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't help completely, you're still using the MSB table constructor, which is not provided by the standard library.

Comment: You only have to make the table once, and it won't affect the speed of the standard library update call.  I don't understand why you want to avoid making your own table.

Comment: The code I currently have makes the table and does the sum. I was hoping that I could remove those lines and depend on the standard library with a minor addition, It seems this is not possible, so I'll just leave the implementation I have as it is.

Answer (score 1):

That equation is simply how to reverse the bits in the *polynomial* (G). The only way to derive a forward CRC from a reverse CRC is to reverse the bits of the *message* as well. Then you can reverse the bits of the resulting CRC. You can reverse the bits of the message with a table lookup, which should be relatively quick. So it *may* be faster to do that along with the built-in CRC, than to just write your own CRC that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I'm just using essentially the MSB code I have here.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a generic [CRC for Go](https://github.com/snksoft/crc). And I believe what you are after is "CRC-32/MPEG-2" in reveng catalog. Yes, name is slightly different, but a rechecked MPEG-TS spec and your question and still believe this is the one you are after. So, you can simply use my implementation with the parameters from reveng catalog. Or if you'd like to have your own implementation for whatever reason, you can still use my code as an example of how to prepare a table and how to use it later. Just keep in mind that LSB is called "reflected" there and MSB is not "reflected" (which is a naming convention introduced by Ross Williams and followed by most implementations).